# Delphi 7 - How to remove a Listview item caption when a client socket disconnect suddenly

Tags: sockets, delphi, listview

hey I'm triyng to delete a item caption from a listview when a client socket disconnect from a server socket suddenly (like the client lost internet connection).
My serversocket1 code:

```
procedure TForm1.socket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject;Socket:TCustomWinSocket);
var
L: TListItem;
begin
L:= Listview1.Items.Add;
l.SubItems.Add(Socket.RemoteHost, socket);
end;
```

this is the code i'm using to delete:(works only when i send the command close to the client).:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject;Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
L:TlistItem;
begin
Listview1.findcaption(0,inttostr(socket.handle),false,true,false,);
if L <> nil then
l.delete;
end;
```

Comment: So your question is actually "How can I tell if a client socket is still connected?" or "How can I get notified when a client socket is disconnected?". You should [edit] your post and ask that question instead, as you apparently already know how to delete an item from a ListView.

Comment: You should also be aware that the socket components you're using have long been deprecated and it's highly discouraged to use them.

Comment: It's also a weak design to store data in a gui control. Use a virtual list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not putting any value in `TListItem.Caption`, but you are trying to use `FindCaption()` as if you had.  I would suggest putting the `TCustomWinSocket` object pointer in `TListItem.Data` and use `FindData()` instead:

```
procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  L: TListItem;
begin
  L := Listview1.Items.Add;
  L.SubItems.Add(Socket.RemoteHost);
  L.Data := Socket;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  L: TListItem;
begin
  L := ListView1.FindData(0, Socket, true, false);
  if L <> nil then
    L.Delete;
end;
```